# Convert NumPy array to x- and y-axis for matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Strugling with this for couple of days now because I' don't fully understand how all the object / datetime conversions work and which are needed for matplotlib. And I can't get beyond the point of try this or that instead of getting more understanding of why I should do things.

I have this numpy array that I loaded from disk ( `combined_list = numpy.load('dumpert.npy', allow_pickle=True)`) (I do this because the data is from external API which has a limit). It has 4 columns, 1=timestamp, 2=price, 3=othertimestamp, 4=power.

```
[datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 21, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        0.16,
        datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 21, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        250],
[datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 22, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        0.16,
        datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 22, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        100]], dtype=object)
```

I then slice the array like this:

```py
rows = len(combined_list)
timestamp = combined_list[0:rows+1,0:1]
prices = (combined_list[0:rows+1,1:2])
solar = (combined_list[0:rows+1,3:4])
```

When I now plot the prices and solar, I get a nice graph:

```py
plt.plot( prices)
plt.plot( solar)
plt.show()
```

But I would actually like two things change:

- have the x-as to use the 'timestamp' and preferably only the hours, like "13:00". Been trying different conversions but I just keep getting different errors.
- have the 'price' be a bar graph instead of plot, but using the following code gives me `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

```py
plt.bar( x=xas, height=prices, width=0.2)
plt.plot( solar)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solutions

- Use `datetime.hour` to get the hours as an integer from the timestamps.
- Flatten the 'price' array using `ndarray.flatten()` from numpy.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

combined_list = np.array([[datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 21, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        16,
        datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 21, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        250],
[datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 22, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        16,
        datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 22, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        100]], dtype=object)

rows = len(combined_list)
timestamp = combined_list[0:rows+1,0:1]
prices = (combined_list[0:rows+1,1:2])
solar = (combined_list[0:rows+1,3:4])

xas = [combined_list[i][0].hour for i in range(rows)]

plt.bar(x=xas, height=prices.flatten())
plt.plot(xas, solar)
plt.show()
```

Links to documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime

Comment: Excellent. I'm always surprised how very difficult tasks in Python can be solved so easily. Never would have thought of [combined_list[i][0].hour for i in range(rows)].